# App Engine frontend waiting for backend to finish and return data - what's the right way to do it?

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine

I'm using a frontend built in angularjs and a backend built in python and webapp2 in app engine.

The backend makes calls to a third party API, fetches data and returns to the frontend.

The API request from the backend may take upto 30s or more. The problem is the frontend can't really progress any further until it gets the data.

I tried running 3 simultaneous requests to the backend using different tabs and 2 of them failed. I'm afraid that this seems to suggest that the app only allows one user at a time.

What's the best way to handle this? One thought I have is:

- Use [task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/?csw=1) to run the API call to 3rd party in the background
- Create a new handler which reads from the queue for the last task sent and let the frontend poll this one at regular intervals
- Update the frontend once data is available

Is that the right way? I'm sure this is a problem solved in a frontend+backend kind of world, but I just don't know what to search for.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe make the front end call synchronous and display an animated gif saying please wait until the api returns the data.

Comment: @whoopididoo - I do that already, but it seems like I keep getting DeadlineExceededErrors

Answer (score 1):

Requests from the frontend are capped at 30 seconds; after that they time out in the server side. That is part of GAE's design. Requests originating from the task queue get 10 minutes, so your idea is viable. However, you'll want some identifier to use for polling, rather than just using "the last sent," to distinguish between concurrent tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I was thinking of something along the lines of using the user email and a unique identifier for the type of request to keep track of it. I'm also looking at endpoints and with it's automatic 10min time period, I'm wondering if that might be the right way to do it.

Comment: You could use an ID like that. I would probably generate a unique ID on the server side when queuing the task, and include that ID in the response back to the front end.

Comment: Grand idea! Thanks, I think I'll use that!